# Reduction mechanism of PSPACE problems to SPACE-TMSAT

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions

To show $\text{PSPACE-completeness}$ of $\text{SPACE-TMSAT}$, we perform a polynomial-time reduction of $\forall L \in \text{PSPACE}$ to $\text{SPACE-TMSAT}$. The language $L$ can be decided by a TM $M$ that takes at most $O(n^k)$ space for some constant $k > 0$. Does the reduction require the value of this constant $k$?

I feel the reduction makes an inherent assumption of the value $k$, I am not sure if this value is required. If the value is required then how do we calculate this?

Edit: [This](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/16768/129110) solution hints towards the above reduction, but this minute detail is not clear to me.

Edit(2): Made the question more clear based on comment

Comment: What do you mean by a reduction of $L$? A reduction from $L$? to $L$? Where does the TM come from? The question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we write $A\leq_p B$, we mean that there exists a polynomial-time reduction from $A$ to $B$, and we don't care whether you have a description of such reduction in hand. So we're trying to prove the **existence** of a reduction. If $k$ is a constant, then there exists machine that encodes this constant, and therefore one can use that machine to conclude the existence of a machine that computes the reduction.